# Finding the uncertainty for the fractal dimension of spatial data using fractaldim package in R

Tags: r

I am able to use the below code to calculate the fractal dimension of a spatial data using R package 'fractaldim'. I need to find an uncertainty value associated with this. The function accesses the fractal dimension of each column and then takes the median value but I cannot figure out how to see each columns calculation and if I could I could calculate an uncertainty. Has anyone been able to do this or able to help me?  NOTE: the data is just a matrix filled with image grey values.

```
#S3 method for class 'matrix'
D <- fd.estimate(data, methods <- "transect.var", window.size <- ncol(data),
            step.size <- window.size, trim <- TRUE, keep.data <- FALSE, 
            keep.loglog <- FALSE, parallel <- FALSE, nr.nodes <- NULL, 
            debuglevel <- 4) #, ...)
```

Comment: Can you make a working example, maybe with a small synthetic data set, just so we can work on something?

Comment: Don't use `<-` when specifying parameters, it has the side effect of creating a variable in the calling context. Compare `x=10000; sqrt(x=9);print(x)` with `x=10000;sqrt(x<-9);print(x)`

Comment: I think your problem might be specifying a window.size that's the size of your data, so you only get one window. But hard to tell without some example code and data.

Comment: this is the package documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fractaldim/fractaldim.pdf           it says to set step.size = window.size

Comment: data <- read.csv("path")
data <- data.matrix(data), i use this code to import the data, sample data can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SrrNNURrg2VQZdLLSqoj61ZQxr7ZNMNy/view?usp=share_link

Comment: The documentation isn't saying you have to do that, its showing the default, which seems to be a window as big as the data, and the same size for the steps, which I think results in one "window" calculation. With a smaller window and a small step size the code computes the fractal D over multiple windows.

Comment: I have tried that and it did not work for me but I have a limited understanding of R as I just started using it recently. Also, I appreciate your help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data is:

```
> dim(data)
[1] 181 347
```

If I compute the fractal dimension with defaults for window and step size, I get one value in the dimension estimate element:

```
> D1 <- fd.estimate(data, methods="transect.var")
> D1$fd
, , 1

         [,1]
[1,] 2.280734
```

...because the default window size is `ncol(data)` and that gives us one window across the data.

If I set a smaller window size, like 10, then the default step size is also 10, and I get 1 output dimension for every ten rows and columns in the data:

```
> D10 <- fd.estimate(data, methods <- "transect.var", window.size=10)
```

Hence my output `fd` element is 1/10 the size of the input, giving estimates of the fractal dimension in each window:

```
> dim(D10$fd)
[1] 18 34  1
```

You can then do stuff like plotting this with `image(D10$fd[,,1])` or computing statistics:

```
> mean(D10$fd[,,1])
[1] 2.297778
> var(c(D10$fd[,,1]))
[1] 0.006012277
```

You'll notice the mean is very close to the mean computed with a single window.

I'm not sure you can treat this as an "uncertainty" though, since I can't relate this to a statistical uncertainty because there's no random variables or model involved. These are just numbers derived from the data in various ways and as such they are absolute truths, not realisations of random variables with associated distributions which let you talk about uncertainty in a statistically strict way.

Comment: Thank you for the help.